# How to read/write an environment variable in a UWP application?

Tags: uwp, environment-variables

In my UWP application I have this code:

```
string tmp = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");
```

But `tmp` is always `null`.
For testing I also have:

```
int i = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables().Count;
```

And `i` is `0`, like my app can't get environment variables.

Some tips?

Comment: i tried your above code it works perfectly in `tmp` i got the path of the file and even in `i` variable i got the count. would you please close the solution and reopen it and build again.

Comment: in `tmp` i got the path e.g **C:\Users\Ketan\AppData\Local\Packages\60c68f85-be4c-4299-fcdc0836f3cb_gr0t6ypwerv6j\AC\Temp** please check the temp folder is available in your package path

Comment: @ketan forgive me but are you using a UWP application? are you sure? I am asking you because your past comment were off my case

Comment: yes i tried this in universal Windows(uwp)

Comment: @ketan ok thanks, i am working on an old UWP project built with VS2015 and published on the store. Maybe something wrong in project files, but it wil be a pain in the AXX

Comment: If you use the lastest version(.e.g vs2019) and create a blank UWP app to test, will the same issue occur?